# In general, is it a bad practice to use the statement "from module import *" in my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I took a python tutorial a year ago and rather enjoyed it, so I thought I'd attempt to incorporate tkinter widgets into things because, well, GUI. Many of the tutorials I have seen covering beginner tkinter begin the code with the line:
 `from tkinter import *`
Is there a compelling reason for this?  I mean, why (or not) load everything?

Comment: It depends but it does pollute the local namespace. If you want a shorter namespace name for `tkinter` you could `import tkinter as tk`. Then your code would look like `tk.<...>`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is a very BAD practice for two reasons:

1. Code Readability
2. Risk of overriding the variables/functions etc

---

For **point 1**:
Let's see an example of this:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *
from module3 import *

a = b + c - d
```

Here, on seeing the code no one will get idea regarding from which module `b`, `c` and `d` actually belongs.

On the other way, if you do it like:

```
#                   v  v  will know that these are from module1
from module1 import b, c   # way 1
import module2             # way 2

a = b + c - module2.d
#            ^ will know it is from module2
```

It is much cleaner for you, and also the new person joining your team will have better idea.

For **point 2**: Let say both `module1` and `module2` have variable as `b`. When I do:

```
from module1 import *
from module2 import *

print b  # will print the value from module2
```

Here the value from `module1` is lost. It will be hard to debug why the code is not working even if `b` is declared in `module1` and I have written the code expecting my code to use `module1.b`.

If you have same variables in different modules, and you do not want to import entire module, you may even do:

```
from module1 import b as mod1b
from module2 import b as mod2b
```